# FileBeat: Only host field shown as JSON, not as string

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am working on Filebeat, where I am pushing the data from our application and system logs to ES domain on AWS. It's working fine, just that the host field as a type is shown as JSON instead of plain-text. I checked the fields.yml file, but no reference to host with JSON as the output.

filebeat.yml :

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/nginx/*.log
  fields:
    type: develop.gateway.nginx.log
    environment: develop.gateway
    service: nginx
  document_type: filebeat.develop.gateway
  registry: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/www/html/api-gateway/deploy/var/log/*.log
  fields:
    type: develop.gateway.application.log
    environment: develop.gateway.application
    service: gateway
  document_type: filebeat.gateway.develop
  registry: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

- type : log
  paths:
    - /var/log/php*.log
  fields:
    type: develop.1c.php-fpm.log
    environment: develop.1c
    service: php-fpm
  document_type: filebeat.php-fpm.1c
  registry: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["OUR_DOMAN"]
  protocol: "https"
```

Comment: What is the issue? do you expect the `host` to be a string? Please paste a sample document (from Elasticsearch). also you can add the index mappings.

Comment: The `host` field is a JSON object, the exported fields will depend on the beat that you are using. What is your issue?

Comment: @leandrojmp : Can I change that field to pass data as String? If so, how?

Comment: With only filebeat I don't think you can, you would need to use logstash and some mutate filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick out the hostname from the payload as i do here:

```
output.kafka:
  ...
  codec.format:
    string: '{"version":"1.1","timestamp":"%{[@timestamp]}","short_message":"%{[message]}","file":"%{[log.file.path]}","host":"%{[host.hostname]}"}'
  ...
```

Comment: Where do I add this? In filebeat.yml?

Comment: That's where i have it. I mostly wanted to show the dot function to extract info from the json payloads :)